# CakePHP extended model not inheriting attributes

Tags: php, cakephp, inheritance, model

I apologize if this ends up being a newbish PHP misunderstanding, but anyway, I have the following `Vip.php` file:

```
<?php

class Vip extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'vips';
    public $hasOne = 'VipCredential';
    public $belongsTo = array('User', 'MasterExhibitor');

    public $validate = array();

}

class InviteVipForm extends Vip {

}

class AccreditVipForm extends Vip {

}
```

So, both `InviteVipForm` and `AccreditVipForm` classes should inherit every model attributes from their parent, right? This doesn't happen. I loaded `InviteVipForm` in the controller and printed. Everything is empty or set to default (`useTable`, for example, is set to `invite_vip_forms`, which is of course a table which doesn't exist).

```
AppModel Object ( [useDbConfig] => default [useTable] => invite_vip_forms [id] => [data] => Array ( ) [schemaName] => [table] => invite_vip_forms [primaryKey] => id [_schema:protected] => [validate] => Array ( ) [validationErrors] => Array ( ) [validationDomain] => [plugin] => [name] => InviteVipForm [alias] => InviteVipForm [tableToModel] => Array ( [invite_vip_forms] => InviteVipForm ) [cacheQueries] => [belongsTo] => Array ( ) [hasOne] => Array ( ) [hasMany] => Array ( ) [hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array ( ) [actsAs] => [Behaviors] => BehaviorCollection Object ( [modelName] => InviteVipForm [_methods:protected] => Array ( ) [_mappedMethods:protected] => Array ( ) [_enabled:protected] => Array ( ) [_loaded:protected] => Array ( ) [defaultPriority] => 10 ) [whitelist] => Array ( ) [cacheSources] => 1 [findQueryType] => [recursive] => 1 [order] => [virtualFields] => Array ( ) [_associationKeys:protected] => Array ( [belongsTo] => Array ( [0] => className [1] => foreignKey [2] => conditions [3] => fields [4] => order [5] => counterCache ) [hasOne] => Array ( [0] => className [1] => foreignKey [2] => conditions [3] => fields [4] => order [5] => dependent ) [hasMany] => Array ( [0] => className [1] => foreignKey [2] => conditions [3] => fields [4] => order [5] => limit [6] => offset [7] => dependent [8] => exclusive [9] => finderQuery [10] => counterQuery ) [hasAndBelongsToMany] => Array ( [0] => className [1] => joinTable [2] => with [3] => foreignKey [4] => associationForeignKey [5] => conditions [6] => fields [7] => order [8] => limit [9] => offset [10] => unique [11] => finderQuery ) ) [_associations:protected] => Array ( [0] => belongsTo [1] => hasOne [2] => hasMany [3] => hasAndBelongsToMany ) [__backAssociation] => Array ( ) [__backInnerAssociation] => Array ( ) [__backOriginalAssociation] => Array ( ) [__backContainableAssociation] => Array ( ) [__safeUpdateMode] => [_insertID:protected] => [_sourceConfigured:protected] => [findMethods] => Array ( [all] => 1 [first] => 1 [count] => 1 [neighbors] => 1 [list] => 1 [threaded] => 1 ) [_eventManager:protected] => [_validator:protected] => )
```

Could anybody tell me why this is happening? The classes don't need to be in separate files, do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how things work, each model has to be placed in a separate file, otherwise CakePHP might not be able to find/load them, and then you'll end up with an instance of the `AppModel` class being used, which is what you are experincing.

The `AppModel` instance of course won't have any of the properties or methods that you've defined on your extending class.

This behavior is also mentioned in the Cookbook, see **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html**

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot find a corresponding file in `/app/Model`. This also means that if your model file isn’t named correctly (for instance, if it is named `ingredient.php` or `Ingredients.php` rather than `Ingredient.php`), CakePHP will use an instance of `AppModel` rather than your model file (which CakePHP assumes is missing). If you’re trying to use a method you’ve defined in your model, or a behavior attached to your model, and you’re getting SQL errors that are the name of the method you’re calling, it’s a sure sign that CakePHP can’t find your model and you need to check the file names, your application cache, or both.

Comment: I see. Shame on me for missing that part. Thanks!