# How to call user defined custom methods in model cakephp2.10

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How do I call already created custom actions in my model from the controller

It seems to be working fine in cakephp1.x version. But when I try to upgrade it into cakphp2.10 methods are not working showing below error

> Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'getChildCategory' at line 1

My code is

Controller call

```
$this->loadModel('Category');
```

$childCategories = $this->Category->getChildCategory();

Model function

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Category extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Category';
var $displayField = 'Category_cname';

public function getChildCategory()
{
     $Db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);

    $cattbl = $Db->fullTableName('categories');
    $dat    =   $this->query("select yt.cname,yt.id
from $cattbl yt
where not exists (select null from $cattbl where parent_id = yt.id) LIMIT 0,10");
    return $dat;

}
```

}

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: It means that there is a syntax error in your query. Please check that.

Comment: I commented all the code inside the method and tried again but showing the same error. Is there any syntax issue in my method declaration???

Comment: `$this->Category` is not an instance of the class where you've defined that method. **https://stackoverflow.com/a/27176539/1392379**

Comment: no,I created the method exactly inside 'Category' model. Please check the updated model code.

Comment: I didn't deny that, I said `$this->Category` is not what you think it is, if you read the quote from the Cookbook, it describes exactly what you are seeing. Check `debug(get_class($this->Category))`. ps, please use @username if you answer someone with a comment, otherwise it's not ensured that they'll be notified about your reply, I just saw it by chance

Comment: When I put 'debug(get_class($this->Category)' code, it shows ''AppModel' text on the screen - @ndm

Comment: the issue is fixed now. The issue is due to the incorrect model name, my model name is 'category' I changed it into 'Category'. @ndm

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the incorrect model name, my model name is 'category' I changed it into 'Category'. Now issue is solved